# How to set a max number of checkboxes that can be selected

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I only allow some maximum number of checkboxes to be selected?

Answer (score 1):

To limit the number of checkboxes that a user can select:

1. Find the Show Custom Error option in the Choice field settings, and set the following expression as your custom error:

   `=Choice.Count() > 2`

Make sure to replace "Choice" with the name of your Choice field, and "2" with the maximum number of checkboxes that can be selected.

2. Create an error message that will display when the user attempts to select more than the maximum number allowed ("Please select no more than two options.")
3. The field will now display an error if the user attempts to select three or more options:

   [image]
4. You can also set a minimum along with your maximum:

   `=Choice.Count() < 1 or Choice.Count() > 2.`